# Send plain text request body with apollo-link-rest

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-link-rest

I am trying to send a POST request to an endpoint that takes a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` `Content-Type` and a plain text string for the form data with the `apollo-link-rest` module and am having the hardest time.

In cURL form the request I want to make looks like this:

```
curl -X POST http://tld.com/search -d include_all=My%20Search%20Term
```

I have wrapped my main component in the `graphql` HOC from `react-apollo` like this.

```
export default graphql(gql`
  mutation productSearch($input: string) {
    search(input: $input) @rest(
      path: "/search",
      method: "post",
      endpoint: "search",
      bodySerializer: "search"
    ) {
      total
    }
  }
`,
{
  props: ({ mutate }) => ({
    runSearch: (text: string) => {
      if (mutate) {
        mutate({
          variables: {
            input: `include_all=${encodeURIComponent(text)}`,
          },
        });
      }
    },
  }),
})(SearchResults);
```

The search `bodySerializer` referenced in the query looks like this.

```
const searchSerializer = (data: any, headers: Headers) => {
  headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  return { body: data, headers };
};
```

And then have called the `runSearch` function like this in my component.

```
async componentDidMount() {
  try {
    const result = await this.props.runSearch(this.props.searchText);
  } catch (error) {
    // report error & show message
  }
}
```

Now I realize I'm not doing anything with the results but there seems to be an unhandled promise rejection (that's what React Native is telling me with a yellow box warning) when running the search code. I'm examining the request with Reactotron as well and the request looks good, but it fails still. I'm wondering if I'm missing something with how I'm configuring `apollo-link-rest` or if there's a better way I can examine requests made from the Apollo client.

Any help here would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that I had everything setup correctly above. Instead of it being an issue with `react-apollo` it was an issue with my Info.plist file. I hadn't enabled the ability of the iOS app to make HTTP requests. It was only allowing HTTPS. I fixed it with this entry in my Info.plist.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```